# Conditionally add multiple items to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm constructing a dictionary in Python from many elements, some of which are nan's and I don't want to add them to the dictionary at all (because then I'll be inserting it into database and I don't want to have fields which don't make sense).

At the moment I'm doing something like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

for i in range(len(data)):
    mydict = OrderedDict([("type", "mydata"), ("field2", data.ix[i,2]), ("field5", data.ix[i,5])])

    if not math.isnan(data.ix[i,3]):
        mydict['field3'] = data.ix[i,3]

    if not math.isnan(data.ix[i,4]):
        mydict['field4'] = data.ix[i,4]

    if not math.isnan(data.ix[i,8]):
        mydict['field8'] = data.ix[i,8]

    etc....
```

Can it be done in a flatter structure, i.e., defining an array of field names and field numbers I'd like to conditionally insert?

Comment: Are you appending values in dictionary during runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> fields = [float('nan'),2,3,float('nan'),5]
>>> {"field%d"%i:v for i,v in enumerate(fields) if not math.isnan(v)}
{'field2': 3, 'field1': 2, 'field4': 5}
```

Or an ordered dict:

```
>>> OrderedDict(("field%d"%i,v) for i,v in enumerate(fields) if not math.isnan(v))
OrderedDict([('field1', 2), ('field2', 3), ('field4', 5)])
```

Comment: +1 for making it a one-liner (apart from defining set of fields). This  is the idea I'll use for sure.

Comment: @sashkello make sure to set the `start` parameter of `enumerate` to the appropriate value based on your naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

for i in range(len(data)):
    mydict = OrderedDict([("type", "mydata"), ("field2", data.ix[i,2]), ("field5", data.ix[i,5])])
    # field numbers
    fields = [3,4,8]
    for f in fields:
        if not math.isnan(data.ix[i,f]):
            mydict['field'+str(f)] = data.ix[i,f]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
conditional_fields = ((3, 'field3'), (4, 'field4'), (8, 'field8'))

for i in range(len(data)):
    mydict = OrderedDict([("type", "mydata"), ("field2", data.ix[i,2]), ("field5", data.ix[i,5])])
    for (index, fieldname) in conditional_fields:
        if not math.isnan(data.ix[i, index]):
            mydict[fieldname] = data.ix[i, index]
```

I am assuming the actual field names are not literally 'field8' etc.